# Istio 504 on ALB to EKS node other than Istio gateway is located

Tags: istio, aws-application-load-balancer

#### Bug Description

I'm using EKS (1.23) and ALB. ALB is terminating TLS with certs provided by ACM.

Using terraform I installed in EKS cluster following helm charts:

- istio-base
- istiod
- gateway

all `1.15.0` version.

Other things configured on cluster:

- aws_security_group_rules, both ingress and egress, on EKS nodes for ports 15000-15090
- required k8s namespaces
- required k8s ingress configuring ALB via alb-controller
- required ACM certificates for ALB
- required Route53 DNS entries

All those things are quite common so I do not think there is any weird stuff there. I have it in multiple places configured that way without Istio.

I also added some httpbin `Service` and `Deployment` and related `Gateway` and `VirtualService`.

In ingress I have 2 paths configured (besides `ssl-redirect` directive for ALB):

- `/healthz/ready` is pointing to `status-port`
- and then `/` is pointing to `http2`

Ingress-gateway service is NodePort type, as required for this type of setup.

(Important) There is 2 nodes in the cluster.

AWS console Target Group details page shows that 2/2 targets are healthy.

Sooooooo ...

When I enter address `https://httpbin.somedomain.com` every second request gets `504 Gateway Timeout`. When I enter `https://httpbin.somedomain.com/healthz/ready` I get 200 every time. When I increase amount of nodes in cluster to 3, 504 occurs for 2 out of 3 requests.

It's quite clear to me, that it's related to ALB round robin over machines ... but why? `status-port` is 200 always.

#### Version

```
$ istioctl version
client version: 1.15.0
control plane version: 1.15.0
data plane version: 1.15.0 (3 proxies)
```

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.2
Server Version: v1.23.7-eks-4721010
```

```
$ helm version --short
v3.8.0+gd141386
```

#### Additional Information

```
$ istioctl bug-report

Target cluster context: v2-xxx

Running with the following config: 

istio-namespace: istio-system
full-secrets: false
timeout (mins): 30
include: {  }
exclude: { Namespaces: kube-node-lease,kube-public,kube-system,local-path-storage }
end-time: 2022-09-27 17:29:26.34498 +0200 CEST



Cluster endpoint: https://yyy.yl4.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com
CLI version:
version.BuildInfo{Version:"1.15.0", GitRevision:"e3364ab424b70ca8ee1ca76cb0b3afb73476aaac", GolangVersion:"go1.19", BuildStatus:"Clean", GitTag:"1.15.0"}

The following Istio control plane revisions/versions were found in the cluster:
Revision default:
&version.MeshInfo{
    {
        Component: "pilot",
        Info:      version.BuildInfo{Version:"1.15.0", GitRevision:"e3364ab424b70ca8ee1ca76cb0b3afb73476aaac", GolangVersion:"go1.19", BuildStatus:"Clean", GitTag:"1.15.0"},
    },
}

The following proxy revisions/versions were found in the cluster:
Revision default: Versions {1.15.0}


Fetching proxy logs for the following containers:

argocd//argo-cd-argocd-application-controller-0/application-controller
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-applicationset-controller/argo-cd-argocd-applicationset-controller-9dddcffbf-zrcgl/applicationset-controller
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-dex-server/argo-cd-argocd-dex-server-75c975ccb7-xmd82/dex-server
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-notifications-controller/argo-cd-argocd-notifications-controller-5854964cbf-z8nlr/notifications-controller
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-redis/argo-cd-argocd-redis-664b98cfd7-lndsf/argo-cd-argocd-redis
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-repo-server/argo-cd-argocd-repo-server-75f49f7ccf-xsblh/repo-server
argocd/argo-cd-argocd-server/argo-cd-argocd-server-6599d8d846-dqr6s/server
first/httpbin/httpbin-7bffdcffd-2klzj/httpbin
first/httpbin/httpbin-7bffdcffd-2klzj/istio-proxy

...

istio-ingress-internal/internal/internal-554ddcb684-kr52c/istio-proxy
istio-ingress-internet-facing/internet-facing/internet-facing-555fd48d8d-2tx74/istio-proxy
istio-system/istiod/istiod-86cd5997bb-r6797/discovery

...

Fetching Istio control plane information from cluster.

Running istio analyze on all namespaces and report as below:
Analysis Report:
Info [IST0102] (Namespace argocd) The namespace is not enabled for Istio injection. Run 'kubectl label namespace argocd istio-injection=enabled' to enable it, or 'kubectl label namespace argocd istio-injection=disabled' to explicitly mark it as not needing injection.
Info [IST0102] (Namespace default) The namespace is not enabled for Istio injection. Run 'kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled' to enable it, or 'kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=disabled' to explicitly mark it as not needing injection.
Info [IST0118] (Service argocd/argo-cd-argocd-applicationset-controller) Port name webhook (port: 7000, targetPort: webhook) doesn't follow the naming convention of Istio port.

...

Creating an archive at /Users/zzz/bug-report.tar.gz.
Cleaning up temporary files in /var/folders/l4/82mt4l7x4r5dzp1j4ppxqqzm0000gn/T/bug-report.
Done.
```

Original issue [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/41197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with allowing port `80` to be allowed between machines in EKS node group. I do not understand why does it help TBH.